# How to Pass a String or Variable with HTTP Redirect in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, controller

I'm developing a quiz and want to check if a question is answered already. Then I'd like to print something and/or disable the form after submitting. The page will be redirected back to show the new option if the user has any observation or reservation. If the form redirects back how can I check or disable the form so a user can't submit the form again? I am using the following method to redirect back.

```
<?php

return redirect()->back();
```

If I pass a variable using the with() method I get no success. The system doesn't recognize my variable. I also tried...

```
<?php

return redirect()->back()->withDisable('disable');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `with` should do it.  For example:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'disable');
```

This is saved in the session data, so you could check for it with:

```
@if (session('status'))
...
```

From: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: thanks, i resolved my issue with you help but i cant accept your answer because stackflow allow me within 2 mins to accept this question.

Answer (score 2):

you can use flash data in laravel for this kind of task.

**What is Flash Data?**

Flash data helps you to store items in the session only for the next request.Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted.

```
$request->session()->flash('disabled', 'true');
```

However, If you need to keep your flash data around for several requests

```
$request->session()->keep(['disabled', 'true']);
```

to access your session/flash data you can simply do

```
$request->session()->all() //all flash session data

$request->session()->get('disabled') // for specific
```

hope that helps